# How to optimize sub query in kohana

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

**models.php**

```
     ->add_subquery('(SELECT character_name FROM zid_character_details WHERE character_detail_id = (SELECT character_detail_id from zid_guild_feeds where feed_id = feeds.guild_parent_feed_id)) AS guildcharacter')
     ->add_subquery('(SELECT character_detail_id FROM zid_character_details WHERE character_detail_id = (SELECT character_detail_id from zid_guild_feeds where feed_id = feeds.guild_parent_feed_id)) AS guildcharacter_id')
     ->add_subquery('(SELECT character_icon FROM zid_character_details WHERE character_detail_id = (SELECT character_detail_id from zid_guild_feeds where feed_id = feeds.guild_parent_feed_id)) AS guildcharacter_icon')
```

Above is the three sub-query I am using to take the `character_name`, `character_detail_id` & `character_icon` from `zid_character_details` table with reference from `zid_guild_feeds` table.

Can anyone tell me how to optimize this three query into single or simple one.

Thanks

Comment: Look into [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), if you already have and for whatever reason it is not possible please include your table structure and tell us what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Kohana Query Builder Joins](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/query/builder#joins) and [Kohana Query Builder Subqueries](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/database/query/builder#subqueries)

When you need to explore various ORM's, I would advise that you have a look at [Leap ORM](https://github.com/spadefoot/kohana-orm-leap)